# Confused about Observable vs. Single in functions like readCharacteristic()

Tags: rx-java2, rxandroidble

In the RxJava2 version of `RxAndroidBle`, the functions `readCharacteristic()` and `writeCharacteristic()` return `Single<byte[]>`.

The example code to read a characteristic is: 
`device.establishConnection(false).flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(characteristicUUID))`

But the documentation for `flatMap()` says the mapping function is supposed to return an `ObservableSource`. Here, it returns a `Single`. How can this work?

Update: I looked at possibilities using operators like `.single()` and `.singleOrError()` but they all seem to require that the upstream emits one item *and then completes*. But `establishConnection()` doesn't ever complete. (This is one reason I suggested that perhaps `establishConnection()` should be reimagined as a `Maybe`, and some other way be provided to disconnect rather than just unsubscribing.)

Answer (score 2):

You're totally correct, this example cannot be compiled. it's probably leftover from RxJava1 version, where `Single` wasn't exists.
Simple fix with the same result is to use RxJava2 `flatMapSingle` for instance:

```
device.establishConnection(false)
            .flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(characteristicUUID))
```

`flatMapSingle` accepts a `Single` as the return value, and will map the success value of the input `Single` to an emission from the upstream `Observable`.

The point is, that RxJava has more specific `Observable` types, that exposes the possible series of emission expected from this `Observable`. Some methods now return `Single` as this is the logical operation of their stream (`readCharacteristic()`), some `Observable` as they will emit more than single emission (`establishConnection()` - connection status that can be changed over time).
But RxJava2 also provided many operators to convert between the different types and it really depends on your needs and scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob!

In fact, the README was deprecated and required some pimping here and there. Please have a look if it's ok now.

Comment: I see that `.flatMapSingle()` fixes the compile error (in fact I had considered it), but the semantics still don't seem quite right to me. The result is still an `Observable`, when it seems like the result of reading a single characteristic value really should be a `Single`, with either "success" or "error".

Comment: Well, in fact, yes. You can do some operations on a write/read result within the flatmap and you will have a `Single`. You can also try sharing the connection using `publish` operator, similar to a strategy Jake Wharton presented in his "Managing State with RxJava" talk.

Comment: Here's what I came up with:     ```Single<byte[]> readCharacteristicSingle( RxBleDevice device, UUID characteristicUUID ) {
        return Single.fromObservable(
                         device.establishConnection( false )
                               .flatMapSingle( connection -> connection.readCharacteristic( characteristicUUID ) )
        );
    }```

Comment: This isn't a good idea, the contract and convention of the library are to keep the device connected as long as the subscription is active. The consequence of using `Single.fromObservable` is that after first emission the observable gets disposed. Keep in mind that back when this was designed Singles and Completables werent existing yet :)

Comment: Anyway, in your example, you could use `flatMap` instead of `flatMapSingle`

Comment: Confused: `Single.fromObservable()` docs say "If the source `Observable` has more than one element, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is signaled." But this could never happen if the subscription is disposed immediately after receipt of the first element. The `Single` would have to maintain the subscription until it received either `onNext()` [causing an error], `onComplete()` [causing it to unsubscribe], or `onError` [presumably passed downstream].

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer I was looking for. The crucial point: 
`Single.fromObservable(observableSource)` doesn't do anything until it receives the *second* item from `observableSource`! Assuming that the *first* item it receives is a valid emission, then if the *second* item is:

- `onComplete()`, it passes the first item to `onSuccess()`;
- `onNext()`, it signals `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since a `Single` can't emit more than one item;
- `onError()`, it presumably forwards the error downstream.

Now, `device.establishConnection()` is a 1-item, *non-completing* `Observable`. The `RxBleConnecton` it emits is flatMapped to a `Single` with `readCharacteristic()`. But (another gotcha), `flatMapSingle` subscribes to these `Single`s and combines them into an `Observable`, which doesn't complete until the source `establishConnection()` does. But the source doesn't ever complete! Therefore the `Single` we're trying to create won't emit anything, since it doesn't receive that necessary *second* item.

The solution is to force the generation of `onComplete()` after the first (and only) item, which can be done with `take(1)`. This will satisfy the `Single` we're creating, and cause it to emit the Characteristic value we're interested in. Hope that's clear.

The code:

```
Single<byte[]> readCharacteristicSingle( RxBleDevice device, UUID characteristicUUID ) {
    return Single.fromObservable(
            device.establishConnection( false )
                    .flatMapSingle( connection -> connection.readCharacteristic( characteristicUUID ) )
                    .take( 1L )  // make flatMapSingle's output Observable complete after the first emission
                                 // (this makes the Single call onSuccess())
    );
}
```

Comment: Update: this approach will connect BLE, read the characteristic, and then disconnect. That may not be your desired behavior. If you want a persistent connection then you probably want to use one of the connection sharing techniques.